# preventDefault not working with wordpress noConflict

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

For the life of me, I'm not able to prevent the default page reload after calling these functions at the bottom of my wordpress index.php.

I've converted the scripts to be compatible with Wordpress' own noConflict mode to the best of my knowledge, but for some reason this isn't flowing through to the following calls.

Should I be calling these scripts in the header to bring them in before wordpress load all of the content in each page? Or is there a problem with my syntax?

(no console errors are being recorded)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".articleTitle a").click(function($){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    var post_id = $(this).attr("href");

    $(".articleTitle a").preventDefault();


    $("#fold-above").css('display','none');
    $("#fold-above").fadeIn(300);
    $("#fold-above").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajaxpost/",{id:post_id});

    return false;
});
</script>


<!-- load files into ajax box and scroll it down: -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).on('click', '.closeUp', function(){
    var video = document.getElementById("postvideo");

    video.pause();
    $("#fold-above").slideToggle();
    $("#fold-above").empty();

});
 });
</script>
```

Comment: What makes you think you can just call it on an element, it should probably be used on an event parameter.

Comment: The `preventDefault` is called on an `event`, not a DOM node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `preventDefault` like that, just try following code

```
jQuery(".articleTitle a").click(function ($) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    var post_id = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $("#fold-above").css('display', 'none');
    $("#fold-above").fadeIn(300);
    $("#fold-above").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajaxpost/", {
        id: post_id
    });

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b2cK2/

Comment: Your solution for placing the preventDefault call makes more sense since it's the first in succession, but afterwards console outputs the following error which I didn't have before `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'ajaxSetup' `

Answer (score 0):

The event gets passed to the anonymous function.  The `preventDefault` method is then called on the `event`.

```
jQuery(".articleTitle a").click(function(event){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    var post_id = $(this).attr("href");

    event.preventDefault();


    $("#fold-above").css('display','none');
    $("#fold-above").fadeIn(300);
    $("#fold-above").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajaxpost/",{id:post_id});

    return false;
});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: When assigning `(e)` my console starts to output this `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'ajaxSetup'` which I'm only guessing, is because for some reason jQuery is looking for the `$` which was originally in the function call. Is this a wordpress Ajax problem?